# Mui Drawer animation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Mui drawer for a company project, it's using a variant drawer. The open and close for the drawer is instanuously and I want it to be able to slowly shift in and out.

The drawer's props and how we use it is fairly simple.

```
<Drawer variant="persistent" {...drawerProps}>
```

and the props is

```
const drawerProps = {
    className: "staff-drawer",
    open,
    onClose
};
```

There're no CSS or any thing controlling the enter or exit transaction.
I have tried to give it a transactrionDuration="1000ms" property, and it doesn't seems to add any transition effect.

Thanks for reading all the way to here, any thoughts or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: that should be the default behavior as the transition is baked into the mui drawer

Comment: yeah, I agree, all the example online that I found they all having a transition even after I delete all the css transition lines. Are there any property that could potentially disabled that?

Comment: I don't think so, I wonder if mui is properly installed etc and you're using the correct imports are you using mui 5?

Comment: Hey Rob, I have found out what the problem is, I posted it in the answer. Thanks for you input in this, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Found in the code base having logic that if the drawer's open prop is false, it will return null. This results the instanuous disappear of the drawer.

```
if (!drawerProps.open) {
    return null;
}
```

removed this, and it behaved correctly